# need help stuck on: return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));

Tags: node.js, canvas

I don't know what is the problem im stuck at line 6
I installed canvas thru the terminal: npm install canvas
until I tries this the code worked

```
const {Canvas} = require('canvas');
```

the error is:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: The module '\\?\C:\Users\thesq\Desktop\New folder (2)\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 83. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\thesq\Desktop\New folder (2)\node_modules\canvas\lib\bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
```

Comment: What version of node.js are you using?

Comment: V14.17.3 i think this version

Comment: hello? I'm still need help

Comment: Try re-installing the module like it says there

Comment: i tried over and over again
didnt work

Comment: hi im still need help...
its for everyone
i just dont see where i can post a message in this question

Comment: hi im still need help... its for everyone i just dont see where i can post a message in this question

Comment: @מרוםרוזנר Check my answer and see if it helps

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this error by deleting the node_modules folder and re-installing it again using `npm install` exactly as it says in the error description.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be happening due to another node package. In my case uninstalling sharp (another node image editing package) solved the issue.

```bash
npm uninstall sharp

npm rebuild canvas

npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if packages installed properly or not.

```
update npm
npm install -g npm@latest
```

delete node modules
re-install packages

```
npm install
```

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same issue. I solve it by removing and reinstalling Node Modules AND restarting.

BUT!!! it keeps coming back! I should love to find a more permanent solution to the problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31487338)